# Get one by one Progress Value(%) while Uploading multipal image in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload

I want to upload multipal image.Single image is uploaded and get progress value using delegate didSendBodyData.But while i uploading multipal image at that time get progress value for all images.I want to get one by one progress value for upload all images.My code for uploading image:

```
NSString *urlString = @"/new_api/temp-album1.php?type=image";
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,urlString]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:200.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  NSString *boundary = @"YOUR_BOUNDARY_STRING";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

 //Sending Image :

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@er.jpg\"\r\n", imageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];


 connectionManager *connMang = [[connectionManager alloc] init];
 [connMang startConnectionWithRequest:request handler:handler errorHandler:errorHandler];`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution might be work for you or not.Try to understand follow step

1)Get number of image you want to upload.suppose you have x = 10 image

2)So you can divide your progress bar into 10 equal part

3)Maintain one variable which which is used to your **image number**

4)Suppose image four currently uploaded then you can calculate your progress as follow

```
          (image number*Progress_of_image)/x
```